# Button not redirecting to selected dropdown option's URL

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener, buttonclick

The idea behind what is happening is I want people to be able to select a state on the first dropdown, then if (and only if) they select a state, they can select a school, and if they select a school, they can click the start shopping button that will take them to the selectedSchools corresponding URL. The state and school selections are working how they should, but the start shopping button is not taking me anywhere on click.

Current code can be found here:

https://codepen.io/jambadrewsh1/pen/poOpPzx

```
// Redirect to selected school's URL when "Start Shopping" button is clicked
startShoppingButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const selectedSchool = schools.find(school => school.state === stateSelect.value && school.name ===     
schoolSelect.value);
  if (selectedSchool) {
    window.location.href = selectedSchool.url;
   }
});`your text`
```

Comment: Instead of codepen you might be able to use StackOverlow's own snippet editor (the `<>` button). With that one can click "copy to answer" to fix your issue more easily. Your JavaScript should probably wait until the HTML is rendered..?

Comment: Your button is disabled and you never enable it.

Comment: New code is on the codepen now. It's enabled, but just not linking to the school urls. Right now it is just reloading the page im on instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's opening a new window with the selected url.

Answer (score 2):

Your button is set to disabled in your codepen and you didn't enable it in your JS